# Google Cardboard default distortion values

Tags: android, google-cardboard

Hi I am trying to distort some stereoscopic video footage for viewing with Google Cardboard.  I have been looking through the [Distortion class](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/latest/reference/com/google/vrtoolkit/cardboard/Distortion) and the example project but can not find any distortion values being defined.

Could someone advise what the distortion values should be used for the default 45mm lenses onto a Nexus 5 screen?  The software I am using to process the footage is NukeX which takes 2 [radial distortion](http://help.thefoundry.co.uk/nuke/9.0/#reference_guide/transform_nodes/lensdistortion.html?Highlight=Radial) values.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The distortion values can be retrieved by calling `distortion.getCoefficients()`.  The first two are the ones you need (r^2 and r^4), but they may need to be adjusted to match your units of distance.