# How to adjust photos for google cardboard

Tags: photoshop, distortion, google-cardboard

I have several pairs of photos that I want to display on a google cardboard viewer. When I combine the images and put them next to each other as 2 square pics (one for each eye) they are distorted in the corners. Looking at a few images on the screen they have a pincushion effect. How do I replicate this pincushion effect? What parameters and values am I looking at? Ideally I'd like a solution in photoshop for example.

I did find this

[Google Cardboard default distortion values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27558783/google-cardboard-default-distortion-values)

But I'm not developing an app to do this.

Thanks